# Grafan don't find prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm trying to setup a Grafana and Prometheus monitoring stack.
Grafana which is installed and available at http://my-ip:3000
Prometheus and node-export are also installed and available at http://my-ip:9090 or 9100/metrics

But I can not add Prometheus as datasource from Grafana, it keeps showing me "Not found" error when I save the datasource settings.
I switched the "Access" setting from server to browser, and I realized that it tries to get data from http://my-ip:9090/metrics/api/v1/query, which return a 404

Did I miss something ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following configuration:

```
URL   : http://localhost:9090
Access: Server
```

Comment: Thanks!looks like grafana wasn't expecting the '/metrics' I was adding.